# Can I add a method inside MyUi.java in vaadin?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I've tried to add a method inside `MyUi.java` class in vaadin, but all I get are errors. So, is it actually possible to do so? The reason why I ask is this: basically `MyUi.java` class has a button which when clicked opens up another window (the code for this other window sits in a different class). This button is removed (`button.setVisible(false);`) when clicked and I added a `addCloseListener` to the new window so that when that window is closed it fires an event and calls a function which will allow me to re-display the button. This function needs to sit inside the `MyUi` class as I can't figure out how to access the button which currently sits inside `MyUi` class from a different class.
Some code to make things a little clearer: `MyUi.java` contains the button

```
public class MyUI extends UI {

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {
        final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
        final NewWindow newWindow = new NewWindow();
       final UploaderComponent uploaderComponent = new UploaderComponent();
        //final TextField name = new TextField();
       // name.setCaption("Type your name here:");

      final Button button = new Button("Click Me");
        button.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event)
            {
                //button.setVisible(false);
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                getUI().addWindow(newWindow.getWindow());
                newWindow.getWindow().setContent(uploaderComponent.formLayout);


            }
        });

        layout.addComponents(button );
        layout.setMargin(true);
        layout.setSpacing(true);

        setContent(layout);
        public void testMethod(){//produces errors
        }
    }
}
```

And the window class:

```
public class NewWindow
{
    //public static final Sizeable.Unit PIXELS;
    Window window = new Window();
    public NewWindow(){
        window.setStyleName("wrappingWindow");
        window.setWidth("620px");
        window.center();
        window.addCloseListener(new CloseListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void windowClose(CloseEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println("window closed");


            }
        });

    }
    public Window getWindow(){
        return window;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the errors that you are getting.

Comment: The code you posted seems to try and define a methid inside the `init` method instead of the UI class' body. Is that a typo?

Comment: @Morfic it wasn't a typo, I was just being stupid. Sorry for the schoolboy error, and thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: No problem, and don't sweat it, it happens to all of us once in a while.